# How to specify Spark properties when starting Spark History Server?

Tags: apache-spark

Does anyone know how to set values in the `SparkConf` when starting the Spark History Server?

Answer (score 7):

if you are using `<SPARK_HOME>/sbin/start-history-server.sh` then you cannot specify command line argument but you can specify `SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS` as environment variable and specify the various environment variables like: -

`export SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.ui.port=9000`

but if you are using `<SPARK_HOME>/sbin/start-daemon.sh` script then you can specify multiple command line options. like this: -

`<SPARK_HOME>/sbin/spark-daemon.sh start org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer -Dspark.history.ui.port=9000`

Comment: I need to pass in custom key/values pairs when running <SPARK_HOME>/sbin/start-history-server.sh. I was hoping to use SparkConf but it does not seem like an option. I don't believe SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS will allow custom values to be passed in. Plus, the SparkConf will not have the values set in the SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS. I think my last option is to set the env variable.

Comment: Actually `HistoryServer` creates its own `SparkConf`. Though it will accept JVM arguments using SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS but it will also accept only those variables which are defined in `HistoryServerArguments`. see here about [HistoryServer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/history/HistoryServer.scala#L239) and [HistoryServerArguments](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/history/HistoryServerArguments.scala#L65). So in case of some custom `key=value`, then env variables is your option.

Answer (score 4):

`start-history-server.sh` accepts `--properties-file [propertiesFile]` command-line option to specify the custom Spark properties using `propertiesFile`.

When not specified explicitly, Spark History Server uses the default configuration file, i.e. `conf/spark-defaults.conf`.